# Do we achieve Dependency Inversion Principle using Dependency Injection technique?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dependency-inversion

**Do we achieve Dependency Inversion Principle using Dependency Injection technique?**

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is

The Dependency Inversion Principle in two sentences:

```
High level modules should not depend upon low level modules. Both should depend upon abstractions.
```

and

```
Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.
```

while

The Dependency Injection Pattern is one of the concrete solutions to the application/code composition problem. And yes this solution is implementation of the Dependency Inversion Principle. Probably the most known place to read is Martin Fowler - Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern.

Comment: +1 for explaining it in simple terms :)  So, dependency inversion principle is a corollary to the "Hollywood principle" which states that high level modules should depend on low level modules but not the other way?

Comment: Actually, this answer is wrong. DIP requires that a high-level module depends only on abstractions defined *at this same high level*. Then, low-level modules implement the abstraction defined at the high-level. This allows the high-level module (including the high-level abstractions it uses) to be *reused* in different contexts/applications. DI, on the other hand, is simply a way for objects to obtain references to other objects, through configurable runtime resolution without lookup calls. So, you can have designs that employ DIP but not DI, and vice-versa; they really are independent ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Dependency inversion says “do not seek your dependencies yourself, they will be supplied to you.” Dependency injection is a way of supplying the dependencies to the object from the outside.

Comment: Is dependency inversion one of the applications of Inversion of control principle?

Comment: That’s a lot of words and I’m not very versed in these things, but I’d say yes. It’s all about the same principle: Keep your design loosely coupled, your objects should work as Lego bricks that can be assembled in any way supported by the interfaces.